# PEAR MDB2 is slow. Can anything be done for it?

Tags: mysql, php, pear

I am using PEAR MDB2 on a high load server. Trying to optimize things, I benchmarked (I know I should have done benchmarking way long ago :() and found that only to include the MDB2 files, takes around 25ms. In contrast, using default mysql_ routines takes no time at all. (well, it costs around 0.1 msec to load the config file with passwords etc).

There are some files that are called many times per second and I was wondering if there is something I can do in MDB2 itself to lower those loading times instead of throwing it all out and use plain old vanilla php mysql_ functions.

I really started to hate PEAR lately..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put eaccelerator or APC or any accelerator so as not to re-load and re-compile each file.